# How to extract just a printed table text using regex

Tags: python, regex

I just try to extract using a regex the string that containts the formated table from a text like this:

```
Table: Person

+-------------+---------+
| Column Name | Type    |
+-------------+---------+
| personId    | int     |
| lastName    | varchar |
| firstName   | varchar |
+-------------+---------+
personId is the primary key column for this table.
This table contains information about the ID of some persons and their first and last names.

 

Table: Address

+-------------+---------+
| Column Name | Type    |
+-------------+---------+
| addressId   | int     |
| personId    | int     |
| city        | varchar |
| state       | varchar |
+-------------+---------+
addressId is the primary key column for this table.
Each row of this table contains information about the city and state of one person with ID = PersonId.
```

I want extract just the text formatted as a table, like this:

```
+-------------+---------+
| Column Name | Type    |
+-------------+---------+
| addressId   | int     |
| personId    | int     |
| city        | varchar |
| state       | varchar |
+-------------+---------+

+-------------+---------+
| Column Name | Type    |
+-------------+---------+
| addressId   | int     |
| personId    | int     |
| city        | varchar |
| state       | varchar |
+-------------+---------+
```

Is that posible using regex?

I tried this without success:

```
(\+\-(.*)\-\+\n)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the regexp flag that makes `.` match newline? You'll need a non-greedy regexp so it doesn't match across multiple tables.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I use python, but i would like to know if possible just using a regex?

Comment: What do you mean by "just using a regex"? Regular expressions don't do anything by themselves, you have to use them in a program or with a command like `grep`.

Comment: Have a try with [`re.findall(r"(?:^[+|].+\n?)+", s, re.MULTILINE)`](https://tio.run/##vVPLasMwEDzXX7H45ODUl94CIZQ2B0MaenBPfYBiy1jUksxKaTD4392V7DygKUkvlS@WZmd3RoOa1lZa3fW9kI1GC8iDwMAcojBjm5rP4Jmj0eqNvjC4CePb03XcxQPcwYOut1LBmkkOHWRtw4FWdyW78cPSwnNAKAsn7A5qZqzv7OEvhnnF8AiXAg/4D/jC7MNkYcBWHBoUkmELn7yFfPBUaiTI4e5mkoGXHQ6oTFkmlCHdVCqZFVoB2@it9R3TR9AlGE3yhmEGmCocJHCQ7vfOIygyYZL9pcP@Z4zkviiQG/NPmbBhmg/lTCYXIsuFbWFcZyIzlln@G3xB2lHYHzNbsrwC1DuXh706P@/EJTRoJq5W@yhhJ2zlEp6P7yUtknASBNQkr7h7T8iTUqiC1XWEYbSYfbzG3XtCThaTOJyCmbqKp5dVlq7S9ZKoTrkkKTD2mAXgDCobSUL7/hs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following regex and code in Python3. Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/l2h9Ai/1) link for shown regex.

As per your shown samples it will create 2 values which you can access by `0`th and `1`st items of list generated by `findall` command.

```
import re
value="""....."""  ##Your variable value, since its too long putting .... here.
re.findall(r'^Table: \S+\n+(\+.*\+\n\| Column Name \| Type +\|\n\+-+\+-+\+\n[^+]*\n\+-+\+-+\+)', value, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above regex(only for explanation purposes):

```
^Table:              ##Start of sting followed by Table:
\S+\n+               ##Matching space followed by non-spaces followed by 1 or more new lines.
(                    ##Starting single capturing group here.
  \+.*               ##Matching literal + just before new line.
  \+\n               ##Matching literal + followed by a single new line.
  \| Column Name     ##Matching literal | followed by space and Column Name.
  \| Type +          ##Matching literal | followed by space and Type space(s).
  \|\n\+-+           ##Matching literal | followed by new line and literal + followed by -(occurrences).
  \+-+\+\n           ##Matching literal + followed by -(occurrences) literal + and new line.
  [^+]*\n\+          ##match everything before next occurrence of + followed by new line and +
  -+\+-+\+           ##Matching 1 or more occurrences of - followed by literal + followed by 1 or more - with literal + here.
)                    ##Closing capturing group here.
```

***NOTE:*** Documentation for [findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) function of `re` module is attached in link here. Code is also using `re.MULTILINE` flag of it, you could check documentation link attached to it.